# jQuery: match an element by searching for style="font-size: 70%"?

Tags: jquery, css

How can I match all a-tags which have a font-size of 70%?

```
<a href="/tag/customersproducts" style="font-size: 70%; text-decoration: none;">customersproducts</a> 
<a href="/tag/dealers" style="font-size: 70%; text-decoration: none;">dealers</a> 
<a href="/tag/dealershops" style="font-size: 101%; text-decoration: none;">dealershops</a> 
<a href="/tag/dealersvendors" style="font-size: 120%; text-decoration: none;">dealersvendors</a> 
<a href="/tag/deliverymethods" style="font-size: 70%; text-decoration: none;">deliverymethods</a> 
<a href="/tag/departements" style="font-size: 70%; text-decoration: none;">departements</a> 
<a href="/tag/departments" style="font-size: 104.545%; text-decoration: none;">departments</a>
```

This does not work:

```
$('a[style*=font-size:70%]')
```

This is the page: http://cakeapp.com/tags/all with installed jQuery for testing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is a filter:

```
$('a').filter(function() { return this.style.fontSize == '70%' })
```

Comment: +1 - clearly less *duh* than my now-deleted solution <smacks self in face>.

Comment: Thank you for the generic approach! (.style.fontSize)

Answer (score 1):

The style attribute isn't a string, so that type of selector won't work (in fact, the console in Chrome and Firefox both say "indexOf is not a function" when trying this one).

I don't know how much control you have over this, but have you considered making those sizes a  set of classes instead? It looks like you're calculating each size on the fly, so you might have to do some grouping/rounding to make that work. Alternatively, when you're creating those inline styles, could you also attach a class to items at 70% at the same time?